# How to make HTTP request wait on async function for response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I have the following route function, but all calls to this function exit before the async function is complete so it cant make a then() or catch() call to respond to the HTTP request appropriately.

How do i make the HTTP request "hold/stall" until my promise is complete?

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {

    // validate username and password
    validateCredentials(req)
    .then((msg) => {
        res.send(`Success!`);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).send(err)
    })

})
```

Comment: This code is fine. There either is something wrong with the code that is making the request, or something wrong with the `validateCredentials` implementation. Please posts that code. Are you getting the expected `msg`?

Comment: Add `validateCredentials` code too. To better understanding of what you have done in that function .

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using ES6 in node, you can use `async/await`. This will allow you to wait until the request has finished to continue on.

I used `fetch` for my example.

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  // validate username and password
  let response = await validateCredentials(req)
  if (response.code != 200) {
    return res.status(500).send(err)
  }
  res.send(response.result)
})

async function validateCredentials() {
  let response = await fetch('http://example.com')
  return { result: await response.json(), code: response.status }
}
```

Comment: how is this at all helping?